# Installing Apache web server using docker file

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile

We wanted to install and run apache using docker file.
So our Dockerfile looks like :

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -y  update

RUN apt-get -y install apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/etc/init.d/apache2" ,"start", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

```
sudo docker build -t my-apache-image .

sudo docker container run -d -P --name my-apache-container my-apache-image
```

But the docker container does not work . Any help as to why this instruction
`"CMD ["/etc/init.d/apache2" ,"start", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]"` does not work ?

Comment: Try passing -k argument before start.

Comment: You might be better off using the official apache image, or at least learning from it: `FROM httpd:2.4`. https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using build Dockerfile from official httpd:2.4, not ubuntu:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

so, docker file should look like:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
EXPOSE 80
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

and building/running:

```
$ docker build -t my-apache2 .
$ docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

If you want to run a simple HTML server, add a simple Dockerfile to your project where public-html/ is the directory containing all your HTML.

Edited, adding official httpd docker image.

Comment: Why would you want to use php? Why would anyone want to use PHP? What does PHP have to do with apache other than the fact that some PHP guy thought it was ok to package up an apache httpd server that is in some way related to PHP? What does PHP have to do with the question? What's wrong with using the official apache httpd image?

Comment: I did. The official Apache httpd container. It's in my comment. I down voted because your solution, using a bloated PHP container, is a bad idea unless you specifically need PHP, which the OP has not stated. If you don't like your answers being downvoted, write better answers. The voting system is used to demonstrate to readers which answers are good and which are not, it's not personal. This isn't a good answer.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer that was my fault, I thought for installing apache PHP is required, and didn't dig into official repo, finding with php. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @vova, Noted that we should official docker image. But I was wondering If we try to install apache server manually then why  "CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]" works but "CMD ["/etc/init.d/apache2" ,"start", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]" fails to start the apache server. Curios to know the difference between these two commands.

Comment: @nayak0765 you can do it differently, but better to separate each service to own container, due to dockers best practice. 1 service 1 container

Comment: We need ubuntu exact version, apache2 is just ONE service. Using httpd docker will not help !